# Autoload Custom Library in Zend 1.12

Tags: php, zend-framework, autoload

I am working on a Zend PHP project and I'm trying to separate out the code into a custom library, for example "Custom". At present this mainly consists of some custom forms.

My folder structure is as follows.

```
/project root
 /Library
  /Custom
    /Forms
      /Account
        /Login.php
      Base.php
  /Zend
  ...
```

The Login.php and Base.php have the following naming conventions:

```
class Custom_Form_Account_Login extends Custom_Form_Base
{

}

class Custom_Form_Base extends Zend_Form
{

}
```

Finally, I placed the following line in my application.ini file

```
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Custom_"
```

Then to create the form, I have this in the controller...

```
$form    = new Custom_Form_Account_Login();
```

However when I load the page, I get an error telling me that Custom_Form_Account_Login cannot be found. The include path is displayed and I can see that "/project root/Library" is there so I'm a bit confused as to why the class cannot be found.

I've tried a number of different lines in the application.ini and I have restarted the server upon making changes yet the error still persists.

Other lines I've tried include:

```
autoloadernamespaces[] = "Custom_" //All lowercase
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Custom"  //Without the underscore
autoloaderNamespaces.custom = "Custom_"
autoloaderNamespaces.0 = "Custom_"
```

As mentioned I am using Zend 1.12. I would ideally like to configure this in the .ini file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your folder name is `Forms` (plural) but the class name uses `Form` (singular). In the context you are describing, these need to be the same. `Form` (singular) is probably better as it mirrors the ZF structure.

Comment: thanks! I thought that would be fine as I had the exact same structure under /root folder/appliation initially, then decided to move it out into a separate library and thought it would be alright. I wonder why it was okay under the application folder? Cheers!

Comment: The reason it works in the `application` folder is that there is a resource-autoloader that gets invoked that establishes a bunch of prefix/path mappings. Check out the class `Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader`. Thanks and cheers!